# BigQuery UDF remove from array. How do I anonymously reference an element in a struct?

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

This removes the elements from the array, but it renames the field to v.

Is there a better way to do this?
OR
Can I get the first element of the struct (ex. t[0])?

```
    CREATE TEMP FUNCTION remove(arr ANY TYPE, val ANY TYPE) AS ((
      SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t)
      FROM (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(arr) v) t
      WHERE t.v <> val
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Use below trimmed down version

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION remove(arr ANY TYPE, val ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(v) 
  FROM UNNEST(arr) v
  WHERE v <> val
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing any element (val) from an array (arr) is possible, as you showed. Putting the `t.v` inside the `SELECT_ARRAY_AGG` let the output be as expected.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION remove(arr ANY TYPE, val ANY TYPE) AS ((
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t.v)
    FROM (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(arr) v) t
    WHERE t.v <> val
));
select remove([1,2,3,4,5],3) as array_without_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the first element of a struct is possible. However this is an ugly workaround to do so:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION firstelement(arr string) 
returns string
LANGUAGE js as
"""
var tmp=JSON.parse(arr);
var var1=arr.substring(2,arr.search(':',)-1);
if(!var1.includes('{')) {
    return tmp[var1];
}
""";

Select firstelement(TO_JSON_STRING(A)) as A,  cast(firstelement(TO_JSON_STRING(B)) as int64) as B,
from (
select struct( "4a" as z,2 as b , 9 as bb) as A, struct( 4 as z,2 as b , 9 as bb) as B
);
```

At first the struct has to be converted to a JSON string. The function finds the name of the first entry and holds that information in `var1`. The string is converted toa JSON and the element with the name `var1` is read out and returned by the function as a string. If it was a number, in the select statement a cast as is needed.

Comment: nice work, however it is very complicated to do so. 
`select A.z
from (
select struct( "4a" as z,99 as bb) as A
);` is much shorer to do.